# SDL web8.1.1 Could not execute query Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException (Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service) - Failed to execute query

Tags: sdl-tridion, microservices, dd4t-2, web8-cu1

We have upgraded from Tridion 2013 SP1 + DD4T 1.0 to SDL Web 8.1.1 micro services  + DD4T 2.0 + SDL Web8 CIL proivder

Summary of the issue
- Initially, we did upgrade SDL Web 8.1.1 + DD4T 2.0 legacy method without micro services, we had a CPU spikes issue it was working fine everything as expected but some behaviour, for example, 100times or 1000 times working fine and then some trigger trying to execute broker query or taxonomy keyword meta query CPU goes high not coming down because of that website goes down.
 - The following action items were done to investigated took the crash dump file during the CPU high to find out the route cast in the IIS worker app pool in process java JVM objects takes High CPU also noticed private memory also increasing from ~2GB to ~6GB

- And then decided to upgraded to micro-services, and then CPU issue was gone but we are getting now new issue very often getting this below error message and website getting 500 Internal server error.

None of the database broker database queries was succedded, we also noticed broker databse CPU was normal at the time.

> ```
> 06:48:49.29  Error    Handle Section At Error occured at HandleSectionErrorAttribute handling - Error occured at
> ```
>
> Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService : HandleException and
>   Handling
>   (http://www.sharjah24.ae/ar/uae/209359-%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%AC%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%B9%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%BA%D9%81%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%88-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%AE-%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%82%D9%8A
>   by 162.158.78.40)
>                    ...      Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException
>   (Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service)
>                    ...      Failed to execute query
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleException(Exception
>   e)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount, Boolean locking)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.ExecuteComponentPresentationMetaDAOMethod(Int32
>   publicationId, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority(Int32
>   componentId)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Common.TridionComponentPresentationProvider.GetContent(String
>   uri, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.TryGetComponentPresentation(IComponentPresentation&
>   cp, String componentUri, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent(String componentUri,
>   IComponent& component, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.BasePageController.GetModelForPage(String
>   PageId, PageType type)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageId)
>                    ...         at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...          System.NullReferenceException (Microsoft.OData.Client)
>                    ...          Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__d(IEdmSchemaElement
>   et)
>                    ...             at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 predicate)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal(IEdmStructuredType
>   edmBaseType, Type type, PropertyInfo[] keyProperties, Boolean
>   isEntity, Nullable`1 hasProperties)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmType(Type type)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.IsSingletonType[TElement]()
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri
>   requestUri, String httpMethod, OperationParameter[]
>   operationParameters)
>                    ...             at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.b__1()
>                    ...             at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
>                    ...
>
>       06:48:49.30  Error    Timestamp   02-Apr-2017 06:48:44
>       06:48:49.30  Error    Machine SMC-WWW2
>       06:48:49.30  Error    Useragent   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; linkdexbot/2.2; +http://www.linkdex.com/bots/)
>       06:48:49.30  Error    Client  162.158.78.40 (162.158.78.40)
>       06:48:49.30  Error    Referrer
>
>       06:48:50.07  Error    {0}: Could not execute query
>                    ...      Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException
>   (Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service)
>                    ...      Failed to execute query
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleException(Exception
>   e)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.b__0()
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount, Boolean locking)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.ExecuteComponentPresentationMetaDAOMethod(Int32
>   publicationId, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority(Int32
>   componentId)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Common.TridionComponentPresentationProvider.GetContent(String
>   uri, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.TryGetComponentPresentation(IComponentPresentation&
>   cp, String componentUri, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent(String componentUri,
>   IComponent& component, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.DD4T.Tridion.Broker.BrokerQuery.<>c.b__22_2(String
>   c)
>                    ...         at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>                    ...         at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>                    ...         at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>                    ...         at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.DD4T.Tridion.Broker.BrokerQuery.Execute(Int32 pageIndex,
>   Int32 pageSize)
>                    ...          System.NullReferenceException (Microsoft.OData.Client)
>                    ...          Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.<>c__DisplayClass19.<GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal>b__d(IEdmSchemaElement
>   et)
>                    ...             at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 predicate)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal(IEdmStructuredType
>   edmBaseType, Type type, PropertyInfo[] keyProperties, Boolean
>   isEntity, Nullable`1 hasProperties)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmType(Type type)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.IsSingletonTypeTElement
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri
>   requestUri, String httpMethod, OperationParameter[]
>   operationParameters)
>                    ...             at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.<Execute>b__1()
>                    ...             at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.b__0()
>                    ...
>       06:48:50.07  Error    Handle Section At Error occured at HandleSectionErrorAttribute handling - Error occured at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable : FirstOrDefault and Handling
>   (http://www.sharjah24.ae/ar/ by 162.158.92.166)
>                    ...      System.ArgumentNullException (System.Core)
>                    ...      Value cannot be null.
>                    ...      Parameter name: source
>                    ...         at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 predicate)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Model.ModelExtension.MainArticles(IPage page,
>   Int32 mainArticleCount, Boolean populateAuthors)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Controllers.PageController.GetIndexModel(IPage
>   page)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Controllers.PageController.GetView(IPage page)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageId)
>                    ...         at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...
>
>       06:48:50.07  Error    Timestamp   02-Apr-2017 06:48:45
>       06:48:50.07  Error    Machine SMC-WWW2
>       06:48:50.07  Error    Useragent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
>       06:48:50.07  Error    Client  162.158.92.166 (162.158.92.166)
>       06:48:50.07  Error    Referrer
>
>       06:48:57.05  Error    Handle Section At Error occured at HandleSectionErrorAttribute handling - Error occured at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService : HandleException and
>   Handling (http://www.sharjah24.ae/ar/sports/international/198729- by
>   141.101.76.154)
>                    ...      Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException
>   (Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service)
>                    ...      Failed to execute query
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleException(Exception
>   e)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.b__0()
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount, Boolean locking)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.ExecuteComponentPresentationMetaDAOMethod(Int32
>   publicationId, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority(Int32
>   componentId)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Common.TridionComponentPresentationProvider.GetContent(String
>   uri, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.TryGetComponentPresentation(IComponentPresentation&
>   cp, String componentUri, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent(String componentUri,
>   IComponent& component, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.BasePageController.GetModelForPage(String
>   PageId, PageType type)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageId)
>                    ...         at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...          System.NullReferenceException (Microsoft.OData.Client)
>                    ...          Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.<>c__DisplayClass19.<GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal>b__d(IEdmSchemaElement
>   et)
>                    ...             at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 predicate)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal(IEdmStructuredType
>   edmBaseType, Type type, PropertyInfo[] keyProperties, Boolean
>   isEntity, Nullable`1 hasProperties)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmType(Type type)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.IsSingletonTypeTElement
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri
>   requestUri, String httpMethod, OperationParameter[]
>   operationParameters)
>                    ...             at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.<Execute>b__1()
>                    ...             at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.b__0()
>                    ...
>       06:48:57.05  Error    Timestamp   02-Apr-2017 06:48:57
>       06:48:57.05  Error    Machine SMC-WWW2
>       06:48:57.05  Error    Useragent   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.2; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)
>       06:48:57.05  Error    Client  141.101.76.154 (141.101.76.154)
>       06:48:57.05  Error    Referrer
>       06:49:07.64  Error    Handle Section At Error occured at HandleSectionErrorAttribute handling - Error occured at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService : HandleException and
>   Handling
>   (http://www.sharjah24.ae/ar/sharjah/172266-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A-%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AD-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85-%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%86%D8%A7-%D9%88%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87%D8%AC-%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%A7
>   by 108.162.245.250)
>                    ...      Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException
>   (Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service)
>                    ...      Failed to execute query
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleException(Exception
>   e)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount, Boolean locking)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.ExecuteComponentPresentationMetaDAOMethod(Int32
>   publicationId, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>                    ...         at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentationWithHighestPriority(Int32
>   componentId)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Common.TridionComponentPresentationProvider.GetContent(String
>   uri, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.TryGetComponentPresentation(IComponentPresentation&
>   cp, String componentUri, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent(String componentUri,
>   IComponent& component, String templateUri)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.BasePageController.GetModelForPage(String
>   PageId, PageType type)
>                    ...         at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageId)
>                    ...         at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>                    ...         at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    ...          System.NullReferenceException (Microsoft.OData.Client)
>                    ...          Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__d(IEdmSchemaElement
>   et)
>                    ...             at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Func`2 predicate)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmTypeInternal(IEdmStructuredType
>   edmBaseType, Type type, PropertyInfo[] keyProperties, Boolean
>   isEntity, Nullable`1 hasProperties)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel.GetOrCreateEdmType(Type type)
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.IsSingletonType[TElement]()
>                    ...             at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute[TElement](Uri
>   requestUri, String httpMethod, OperationParameter[]
>   operationParameters)
>                    ...             at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.b__1()
>                    ...             at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.b__0()
>                    ...

Anyone based this issue, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU High issue was gone after upgrading to microservices.

Internal server Error fixed by upgraded all the **DD4T packages** to the latest release and it includes **NewtonSoft.JSON 10.0.1** (the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a missing value/content somewhere in your index page(s), perhaps a certain type of Component Presentation or a some other attribute.

It looks like the problem lies within the `MainArticles` Model Extension:

```
http://www.sharjah24.ae/ar/ 
 System.ArgumentNullException (System.Core) ... Value cannot be null. ... Parameter name: source
at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Model.ModelExtension.MainArticles(IPage page, Int32 mainArticleCount, Boolean populateAuthors)
```

Perhaps the query returns an empty result and your model extension isn't checking for null, i.e. there is a list it's trying to traverse while looking for an Index Model, but it can't find the index page that maps to the model, or it can't build the model due to some other missing parameter:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable1 source,
  Func2 predicate) ... at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Model.ModelExtension.MainArticles(IPage page, Int32 mainArticleCount, Boolean populateAuthors) ... at Indivirtual.SHARJAH24.Controllers.PageController.GetIndexModel(IPage page) ... at
```

I would look closely at this index page: `http://www.sharjah24.ae/ar/` and see if there is a missing component or metadata parameter or something that isn't to your index page content creation standard.

I would also add some null checks into your `ModelExtension.MainArticles` and throw a custom exception with a clear error message, so that when this scenario occurs again, you know quickly where to go to fix the content issue.